# How to get length of Integer in Pyramid using Deform

Tags: python, range, pyramid, deform

This might be a silly question, but how would I get the length of a number using [deform](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/en/latest/)?

I have the following:

```
class BankingDetails(colander.MappingSchema):
    """ Deform class to add an Agent's Banking Details """
    account_number = colander.SchemaNode(
        colander.Integer(),
        validator=colander.Range(13),
        missing=None,
        widget=deform.widget.TextInputWidget(size=60))

    bank_name = colander.SchemaNode(
        colander.String(),
        validator=colander.Length(max=100, min=3),
        missing=unicode(''),
        widget=deform.widget.TextInputWidget(size=60))

    branch_code = colander.SchemaNode(
        colander.Integer(),
        validator=colander.Range(6),
        missing=None,
        widget=deform.widget.TextInputWidget(size=60))
```

I though that

```
validator=colander.Range(13),
```

would do it, but that only sets the `minimum` value.

I thought [range()](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/range.html) would work as the python method returns a list congaing e.g. 13 entries. obviously I was wrong.

Is there a way for me to get the Integer's length using [pyramid deform](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_deform/en/latest/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Range(max=10 ** 13)` (see the [package documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/api.html#colander.Range)).

As mentioned by Sascha Gottfried below, you can use the `min_err` and `max_err` keyword arguments to set a custom error message.

Comment: Thanks for this... How would I then customize the error message to be number longer than 13? currently it displays `<number> is greater than maximum value 10000000000000`. sorry if its a trivial question... Would I have to create a custom validator for that?

Comment: Colander range validator provides two arguments to customize these messages, look at provided link to package documentation - colander.Range(min=None, max=None, min_err=None, max_err=None)